# Add size chart in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, php

Is there a way to add size chart in magento 2.1. I am new with magento and I am having trouble figuring out the cms. So, the client asked me to add size chart on single product. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please try https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235955/how-can-draw-chart-in-knockout-js-in-magento-2

Comment: Do you want a table in popup on product page for size chart table?

Comment: Try this extension to Add Size Chart. https://marketplace.magento.com/fme-size-chart.html
As per your need, you can add Size Chart on Single Product, you can customize them to Store view also.
I am listing the Key Features of the extension here
1. Create & Customize Size Chart for Products
2. Set Conditions to Assign Size Charts to Specific Products
3. Upload a Size Image & Add Chart Data
4. Display Size Chart in Tab or Popup
5. Restrict Size Charts to Store Views
6. Import Chart Data

Comment: try advanced [magento 2 size chart](https://www.mageants.com/size-chart-extension-for-magento-2.html) extension and test demo as per your requirement

Answer (score 2):

magento2-knockout-chart

Open Url

http://example.com/pulsestorm_knockouttutorial/

More Example

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/

Here this repo Explain

Many time we need to create own graph but in Magento 2 here knockout is using i will try how can we create a chart in Magento 2

https://github.com/mukdam/magento2-knockout-chart/

Answer (score 0):

There are several size chart extensions available out there. Kindly check https://bsscommerce.com/blog/top-10-magento-2-size-chart-extensions-free-and-paid/ . All they need is installation and configuration.
Rest if you want to customize it to show on single product, single category, or whatever. Just customize the code as per your need.

If you are thinking to create a size chart extension then , I believe that will be out of scope for this thread.

If you need anything else. Kindly let me know here.