# how can Draw chart in knockout js in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to draw chart by knockout js.

So check but there is complexity to implement with knockout js in Magento 2 to how can I bind to this with new values.

Not Respond [Add size chart in magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176109/add-size-chart-in-magento-2-1)

Answer (score 3):

I am tried with a library

Create a phtml file

```
<div  data-bind="scope: 'chartscope'"> 
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
```

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "chartscope": {
                        "component": "Pulsestorm_KnockoutTutorial/js/chart"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Create a .html file

```
<div id="line-example">
<h2>Simple Line Chart Example</h2>
<!-- <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(SimpleLineData, null, 2)"></pre> -->
<canvas id="some-simple-line-chart"
        data-bind="chart: { type: 'line', data: SimpleLineData }"></canvas>
<p>The above chart is generated using the data in the view model and rendered into the canvas</p>
```

And add a js

```
define(
    [ 'jquery', 'uiComponent', 'ko','libChart'],
    function($, Component, ko) {

        'use strict';


        ko.observableGroup = function(observables) {
            var observableManager = {};
            var throttle = 0;
            var throttleTimeout;

            observableManager.throttle = function(duration) {
                throttle = duration;
                return observableManager;
            };

            observableManager.subscribe = function(handler) {
                function throttledHandler(val) {
                    if(throttle > 0) {
                        if(!throttleTimeout) {
                            throttleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                                throttleTimeout = undefined;
                                handler(val);
                            }, throttle);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    { handler(val); }
                }

                for(var i = 0; i < observables.length; i++)
                { observables[i].subscribe(throttledHandler); }

                return observableManager;
            };

            return observableManager;
        };

        var getType = function(obj) {
            if ((obj) && (typeof (obj) === "object") && (obj.constructor == (new Date).constructor)) return "date";
            return typeof obj;
        };

        var getSubscribables = function(model) {
            var subscribables = [];
            scanForObservablesIn(model, subscribables);
            return subscribables;
        };

        var scanForObservablesIn = function(model, subscribables){
            for (var parameter in model)
            {
                var typeOfData = getType(model[parameter]);
                switch(typeOfData)
                {
                    case "object": { scanForObservablesIn(model[parameter], subscribables); } break;
                    case "array":
                    {
                        var underlyingArray = model[parameter]();
                        underlyingArray.forEach(function(entry, index){ scanForObservablesIn(underlyingArray[index], subscribables); });
                    }
                    break;

                    default:
                    {
                        if(ko.isComputed(model[parameter]) || ko.isObservable(model[parameter]))
                        { subscribables.push(model[parameter]); }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        ko.bindingHandlers.chart = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
                var chartBinding = allBindings.chart;
                var activeChart;
                var chartData;

                var createChart = function() {
                    var chartType = ko.unwrap(chartBinding.type);
                    var data = ko.toJS(chartBinding.data);
                    var options = ko.toJS(chartBinding.options);

                    chartData = {
                        type: chartType,
                        data: data,
                        options: options
                    };

                    activeChart = new Chart(element, chartData);
                };

                var refreshChart = function() {
                    chartData.data = ko.toJS(chartBinding.data);
                    activeChart.update();
                    activeChart.resize();
                };

                var subscribeToChanges = function() {
                    var throttleAmount = ko.unwrap(chartBinding.options.throttle) || 100;
                    var dataSubscribables = getSubscribables(chartBinding.data);
                    console.log("found obs", dataSubscribables);

                    ko.observableGroup(dataSubscribables)
                        .throttle(throttleAmount)
                        .subscribe(refreshChart);
                };

                createChart();

                if(chartBinding.options && chartBinding.options.observeChanges)
                { subscribeToChanges(); }
            }
        };


        return Component
                .extend({
                    defaults : {
                        template : 'Pulsestorm_KnockoutTutorial/chart'
                    },

                    initialize : function() {
                        this._super();
                        this.SimpleLineData = {
                                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                                datasets: [
                                    {
                                        label: "Healthy People",
                                        backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                                        borderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        label: "Ill People",
                                        backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                                        borderColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                                        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                                    }
                                ]
                            };

                        /* Doughnut and Pie */
                        this.RedValue = ko.observable(300);
                        this.GreenValue = ko.observable(50);
                        this.YellowValue = ko.observable(100);
                        this.DynamicDoughnutData = {
                            labels: ["Red", "Green", "Yellow" ],
                            datasets: [
                                {
                                    data: [this.RedValue, this.GreenValue, this.YellowValue],
                                    backgroundColor: [
                                        "#FF6384",
                                        "#36A2EB",
                                        "#FFCE56"
                                    ],
                                    hoverBackgroundColor: [
                                        "#FF6384",
                                        "#36A2EB",
                                        "#FFCE56"
                                    ]
                                }]
                        };
                    }
                });
    });
```

You can drow more type graph look more example http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/

You can download complete code https://github.com/mukdam/magento2-knockout-chart